# how to minimize cards on android wear?

Tags: android, wear-os, android-wear-notification

I have successfully created a sample card on android wear by referring following tutorial  https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/ui/cards.html

**But my sample card doesn't minimize on down swipe.**

This is the output I'm getting

[image: Only right swipe will work(to dismiss card)]

**I want some thing like this**

[image: Normal stage of wear app running]

and when I swipe down card will minimize like this 
[image: minimized state]

**Just like media player app working on wearable!**

Can anyone help me with this? I have just started learning development for wearable.

Here is my code

```
package com.example.cardsample;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.wearable.view.CardScrollView;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.rect);

          CardScrollView cardScrollView = (CardScrollView)
          findViewById(R.id.card_scroll_view);
          cardScrollView.setCardGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM);

    }




}
```

**rect.xml**

```
<android.support.wearable.view.BoxInsetLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:background="@drawable/ic_full_sad"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_width="match_parent">

    <android.support.wearable.view.CardScrollView
        android:id="@+id/card_scroll_view"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        app:layout_box="bottom">

        <android.support.wearable.view.CardFrame
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp">
                <TextView
                    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:text="Heading"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textSize="20sp"/>
                <TextView
                    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:text="description"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textSize="14sp"/>
            </LinearLayout>
        </android.support.wearable.view.CardFrame>
    </android.support.wearable.view.CardScrollView>
</android.support.wearable.view.BoxInsetLayout>
```

Comment: add your actual code to the question.

Comment: You probably need to declare a custom layout. It's mentioned on the Android developer's site.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider pls check the code

Answer (score 2):

I think what you are looking for is a notification: https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/notifications/creating.html

A notification shows the title when its minimized and when you swipe up it shows the full text or your custom layout (https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/apps/layouts.html).